# Increment the nth digit of a float

Tags: c#, floating-point

I am creating a control where I need to increment or decrement the nth digit of a float number. For instance if I want to increment:

```
12.3456    I want to increment the thousand (5) to 6
     ^
```

then I will write `12.3466`

It is simple to do it when the number is not large (few significant digits). Take for instance `223456.109f` if I then want to increase the first `2` I will like to end up with `323456.109f = 323456.1` (c# rounds 323456.109 to 323456.1 so that it can fit in 32 bits) . What am I doing right now is adding 100000. The problem is that if I add 10000 to `223456.109f` then that will give me `323456.125f` which is not the same as `323456.1f`.

How can I solve this problem. Do I have to convert it to a string then do the math with the string?

### Edit

Thanks to your answer here is my method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Increments the nth digit of a float number
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="floatToIncrement">The number we are incrementing such as 12.34E+20f </param>
    /// <param name="positionToIncrement"> See example inside method. </param>        
    /// <param name="incrementOrDecrement">If true it will increment if false it will decrement</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static float IncrementFloat(float floatToIncrement, short positionToIncrement, bool incrementOrDecrement=true)
    {
        /* Example:
           10.5678

           1 = positionToIncrement ->  2
           0 = positionToIncrement ->  1
           5 = positionToIncrement -> -1
           6 = positionToIncrement -> -2
           etc
         */

        if (positionToIncrement == 0)
            return floatToIncrement;

        var floatToIncrementAsString = floatToIncrement.ToString("R");

        // a float number may be 1.20E+20 let's match it so that we can remove the E+20
        var match = Regex.Match(floatToIncrementAsString, @"(\d[^E]+)(.*)"); 

        var decimalNum = decimal.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);

        // if position is greater than 0 we increment the nth digit to the left of the '.'
        if(positionToIncrement>0)
        {
            var numToAdd = int.Parse("1".PadRight(positionToIncrement, '0'));
            if (incrementOrDecrement)
                decimalNum += numToAdd;
            else
                decimalNum -= numToAdd;
        }
        else // else we do the same but to the right of the '.'
        {
            var x = Math.Abs(positionToIncrement);
            var y = "1".PadRight(x+1, '0');
            var numToAdd = int.Parse(y);

            if (incrementOrDecrement)
                decimalNum += 1 / ((decimal)(numToAdd));
            else
                decimalNum -= 1 / ((decimal)(numToAdd));
        }

        var result = decimalNum + match.Groups[2].Value;

        return float.Parse(result);            
    }
```

Comment: You might be better off using the `decimal` type, unless there is something externally dependent needing the value as a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) data type , it has 28-29 significant digits, so it can solve your problem.

**Approximate Range**

(-7.9 x 10<sup>28</sup> to 7.9 x 10<sup>28</sup>) / (10<sup>0 to 28</sup>)

**Precision**

28-29 significant digits

Compare with `Float`

**Precision**

7 significant digits.

When you have to avoid roundoff error, always use `decimal`.

`decimal` has more significant figures than the `float`, therefore it can be more precise- it also takes up slightly more memory. Other than certain math or physics-related algorithms, the double or float should do fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you need precise value you shouldn't use `float` or `double`. Use `decimal` instead.

> The `Decimal` value type is appropriate for financial calculations that require large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits and **no round-off errors**.
>
> *from [Decimal Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*

Comment: The sentence immediately after the one you quoted states that the Decimal type does not eliminate rounding. Please do not give people the false idea that Decimal has no rounding errors. This leads to problems later.

Comment: `The Decimal type does not eliminate the need for rounding. Rather, it minimizes errors due to rounding.` from [decimal structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)